# How do I resolve a Promise inside a Task?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have a method which should get a location and send its result as a resolved Promise. However I have no idea how to await for the listener to finish or to workaround. It uses Google Services API to get current location.

```java
// LocationModule.java
@ReactMethod
public void getLocation(String debugMessage, Promise promise) {
    try {
        this.fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if(location != null) {
                        promise.resolve(location);
                    }
                }
            });
        // promise.resolve(debugMessage); this would be called before the promise above and if it isn't present here app crashes
    } catch(Exception e) {
        promise.reject("Something went wrong", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify I know i can't just send Location object, but coversion will worry me later

Comment: Your code looks good. Just need declare your promise as `final`.

Comment: It doesn't change anything because it doesn't change when this promise is called.